# Fastest way to iterate over 70 million rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two pandas dataframes `bookmarks` and `ratings` where columns are respectively :

- `id_profile`, `id_item`, `time_watched`
- `id_profile`, `id_item`, `score`

I would like to find score for each couple (profile,item) in the `ratings` dataframe (set to 0 if does not exist). The problem is the `bookmarks` dataframe has 73 million rows and it takes so much time (after 15 min the code continues to run). I suppose there is a better way to do it.

Here is my code :

```
def find_rating(val):
  res = ratings.loc[(ratings['id_profile'] == val[0]) & (ratings['id_asset'] == val[1])]
  if res.empty :
    return 0
  return res['score'].values[0]

arr = bookmarks[['id_profile','id_asset']].values
rates = [find_rating(i) for i in arr]
```

I work on collab.

Do you think I can improve speed of the execution?

Comment: I don't like this `for`-loop which runs `find_rating` for different values. Maybe you could run every `find_rating` in separated thread or process. `pandas` should have extension for multiprocessing. OR maybe you should put all data in SQL server and use  it instead of pandas.

Comment: Take a look at [Dask](https://dask.org/), if you know pandas it shouldn't be too hard to learn and it allows you to speed up your work by using multiple cores (and, if you want to, using cluster of machines too)

Answer (score 0):

Just some thoughts ! I have not tried such large data in Pandas.

In pandas, the data is index on row as well as columns. So if you have 1 million rows with 5 columns ==> we have indexed 5 million records.

For performance boost,

1. Check if you can use Sparse* data structures - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html
2. Filter out the unnecessary data as much feasible.
3. If you can, try stick to using only numpy. As this reduces few features, we also we loose some drag. Worth exploring.
4. Use some distributed multithreaded/multiprocessing tools like Dask\Ray. If you have 4 cores -> 4 parallel jobs => 25% faster